# Problema al pintar en paleta de colores (colr.org)

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

**Componente de react donde se pinta una paleta de colores**

```
function HeaderColor(props) {
```

**Arreglo donde se guardan los colores**

```
  var colors = [];
```

**Peticion de paleta de colores**

```
  axios.get(`https://www.colr.org/json/colors/random/7`)   
    .then(res => {console.log(res.data.colors);
```

**añadir los colores al array**

```
for(var i = 0; i < res.data.colors.length; i++){
```

**Se añaden correctamente los colores al arreglo colors**

```
colors.push("#"+ res.data.colors[i].hex);
      }
      console.log("colors",colors);
    })
    .catch(err   => {
      console.log(err);
    });

  const newgame = () =>{
   props.setGridState(props.grid); 
   props.setSelected(false);
  }
```

> Funcion para imprimir la imagen del dibujo (no relevante)

```
  function print(){
    props.setSelected(true);
    setTimeout(()=>{html2canvas(props.ss.current).then(canvas => {
      
      props.img.current.innerHTML = "";
      props.img.current.appendChild(canvas);
    });},10)
  }

  const handleClick = (event) =>{
    props.setSelectedColor(event.target.name);
  }
```

---

```
  return (
    <div className="menu">
      
      <div id="menuRight">
      <Button onClick={newgame} variant="contained" className="st"
      sx={{
          height:40,
          marginRight:4,
          marginLeft:2,
          borderRadius:3,
      }}
      >New Game</Button>
      <Button onClick={print}  variant="contained"
      sx={{
        height:40,
        marginRight:4,
        borderRadius:3,
    }}
      >Print</Button>
      </div>
        <h3>Choose color to start painting:</h3>

      <div id="menuLeft" >
        <ul style={{display: 'flex', listStyle:'none'}}>}
```

> En este bloque se hace el map del arreglo de los colores (el mencionado arriva), por alguna razon primero se pinta la paleta (como no hay ninguno no sale nada) y luego se agregan los colores al arreglo

```
            {colors.map( (color) => {
            
            
              const isSelected = color === props.selectedColor;
              const borderStyle = isSelected ? '5px solid #66abf4':'2px solid #FFFFFF';

              return (
```

Botones donde se pinta la paleta de colores

```
                <button 
                      key={color}
                      type="button" 
                      onClick={handleClick} 
                      name={color} 
                      style={{
                          width:'50px', 
                          height: '50px', 
                          border: borderStyle,
                          color: 'white', 
                          background: color,
                      }}
                  >   

   

              
                  </button>
              )
          
              })}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En react es una mala idea y siempre se debe tratar de evitar las mutaciones como las que estas haciendo tu al usar push en react siempre se piensa en estados y componentes, lo que tu necesitas es crear un useState y guardar ahi en un array la response que recibes de le api

```
//El estado donde guardaras la data
const [colorData, setColorData] useState([])

//seteas la data
fetch('https://www.colr.org/json/colors/random/7')   
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => setColorData(data.colors))
    .catch(err => conlose.err(err))
```

Despues de aca ya puedes usar el map recorrer colorData que es donde esta guardado el array con la data de axios